# streaming with HLS / hevc / fmp4 not working in safari?

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, http-live-streaming, hevc, fmp4

I am trying to serveHLS streaming in html video tag.
The media was encoded by ffmpeg 5.1, but the h265 codec is not working in safari, while h264 is fine.

demo site: http://47.254.74.168:8080/

Don't know why, any ideas? thanks!

ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -i Big_Buck_Bunny_360_10s_10MB.mp4 -f hls -hls_segment_type mpegts h264-ts/stream.m3u8
ffmpeg -i Big_Buck_Bunny_360_10s_10MB.mp4 -f hls -hls_segment_type fmp4 h264-fmp4/stream.m3u8
ffmpeg -i Big_Buck_Bunny_360_10s_10MB.mp4 -c:v libx265 -tag:v hvc1 -f hls -hls_segment_type mpegts h265-ts/stream.m3u8
ffmpeg -i Big_Buck_Bunny_360_10s_10MB.mp4 -c:v libx265 -tag:v hvc1 -f hls -hls_segment_type fmp4 h265-fmp4/stream.m3u8
```

Answer (score 0):

IOS and Safari do not support hev1 codecID
If you want to serve hevc media on Apple products, you should convert codec id from hev1 to hvc1